# Stop 2 consecutive uses discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am making a discord bot in which an auction could take place.So I want someone to bid only once unless someone bids after him/her.

```
`async def bid(ctx): 

  embed1=discord.Embed(description= f'Bid has been placed by {ctx.author}', title='bid placed')

  await ctx.send(embed=embed1)

       `
```

That's what I have so far made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the author id in a variable:

```
bidderid = 0 #this will reset whenever your bot restarts
@client.command()
async def bid(ctx):
    global bidderid
    if ctx.author.id != bidderid: #if it is not the same bidder
        bidderid = ctx.author.id
        embed1=discord.Embed(description= f'Bid has been placed by {ctx.author}', title='bid placed')
        await ctx.send(embed=embed1)
    else: #if it is the same bidder
        await ctx.send('You cannot bid twice in a row!') #replace with whatever message
```

note: It doesn't have to be the id, you could store `ctx.author` instead, idea is the same